# Find the longest subsequence of A which is odd-even. using python

Tags: python

Given an array of integers A of size N. Find the longest subsequence of A which is odd-even.

A subsequence is said to odd-even in the following cases:

The first element of the subsequence is odd, second element is even, third element is odd and so on. For example: [5, 10, 5, 2, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

The first element of the subsequence is even, second element is odd, third element is even and so on. For example: [10, 5, 2, 1, 4, 7], [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Return the maximum possible length of odd-even subsequence.

Note: An array B is a subsequence of an array A if B can be obtained from A by deletion of several (possibly, zero or all) elements.

Code is below

```
def solve(A):
    n = len(A)
    sln =[]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            if A[i]%2 == 0:
                if A[j]%2==1 and A[j] < A[i]:
                    sln[i] = max(sln[i],sln[j]+1 )

            else:
                if A[j]%2==1 and A[j] < A[i]:
                    max(sln[i],sln[j]+1 )
    return sln
A = [1, 2, 2, 5, 6]
solve(A)
```

I am getting index error `----> sln[i] = max(sln[i],sln[j]+1 )` Why index error is coming `j` is everytime less than i

Comment: `sln = []` but you are accessing it with `sln[i]`.

Comment: Right.  You never append anything to `sln`.

Comment: Aside from that, the logic of your code isn't clear. Why do you need to compare `A[j] < A[i]` when the only thing you concern about is length and parity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a value to an index of a list that doesn't have a value yet:

```
    sln =[]
# ...
                    sln[i] = max(sln[i],sln[j]+1 )
```

You could just append to the solution as you find new matches instead.

Here's a simpler solution altogether though:

```
def solve(a):
    if not a:
        return []
    sln = [a[0]]
    for x in a[1:]:
        if x % 2 != sln[-1] % 2:
            sln.append(x)
    return sln


example = [1, 2, 2, 5, 6]
print(solve(example))
```

The first bit ensures there's no error when an empty list is passed. The solution always includes the first element. Every other element will be included if its value mod 2 is different from the last element in the solution so far.

An even simpler solution (a one-liner in fact), based on the same idea would be this, but it's a bit harder to read, so only better if brevity is a goal by itself:

```
def solve_short(a):
    return [x for n, x in enumerate(a) if not n or x % 2 != a[n-1] % 2]
```

I didn't measure the times, but I would expect `solve_short()` to run faster than `solve()` as well - if that's a consideration.

Note that the short solution makes use of the fact that including any number that doesn't have the same parity as its predecessor in the original list can be included for a correct solution, even though that's not as explicit as the logic in the longer solution.

I was curious and ran a test - the longer solution actually performs better than the short one, but here's one that performs better for most cases:

```
def solve_fast(a):
    return [] if not a else [a[0]] + [x for x, y in zip(a[1:], a) if x % 2 != y % 2]
```

Comment: can you explain a[n-1] % 2 in the scond solution

Comment: The counterpart of `a[1:]` is `a[:1]`. You could start your first and third solution with that.

Answer (score 1):

Two more ways and a benchmark:

```
# inspired by Grismar
def solve(a):
    return [x for x, y in zip(a, [.5] + a) if (x + y) % 2]
```

```
from itertools import groupby

def solve(a):
    return [next(g) for _, g in groupby(a, 1 .__and__)]
```

Benchmark times for `a = random.choices(range(100), k=10**6)`:

```
124 ms  124 ms  128 ms  125 ms  127 ms  Grismar1
172 ms  228 ms  291 ms  178 ms  180 ms  Grismar2
102 ms  105 ms  106 ms  102 ms  106 ms  Grismar3
 96 ms   86 ms   89 ms   85 ms   85 ms  dont_talk1
162 ms  179 ms  165 ms  166 ms  165 ms  dont_talk2
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbjtsgEH3nK6aqVgupa8Wxtqoi@bkfYVkWsScJig0WkNbuz6dgfEmyu1J5MTDDOWeYg7vBnpVMf3b6djtq1YLmsnYf0XZKW6jOSlRoyBiyokVh55DGDrkNEWFRW6UaMwdPWl27w0BIjUf4pYVpuU4oZ3sCbogjSGWBh5UfGu1VS8iLccc0EjLIeb4twsZRaehBSOB5si/WYw6ohxfYwZfMH8q/J4VfrgkTWsy7DmVNe0bu2FzgQeBuETjL6UdmGQVylNcWNbfo8uYaJIzSJg08l5OE4gE5fYdcLJcA2BicioVvM2cfweA5/4qOjkVHEEgXruGOplbSlpY3l@STEh7gIsjjN88VEGnvpgP7CO79jUjsLT2xEbSM4ORBp2Z74ATisnQOKkvmsIxqfqM2rpezBaLlrpdZGt3Jv5vvCPkKldIaKyvRGKBGtfjnzG0cx6BkMzh3YnUx0KA82bNhxIsKCy/LOfmEdLedKhgVr/vJvO8HdxInq9M5vGURXLIAx5ZM7Dunx6VPtbmuuf7sizXD84SgJ5vSHh2p0VybFeQJYBRkjHtRvhgakhlk2bgMAhghT/WkUzmfl5JsN5sfjPyHxkp1An3b/LumuZf3fH1v7E6x/zH49PBLoA1vDzXfz9WNlgmQzAlxj@iAOkvW450W0tINfX1Ja2gNvDorUgsbSDANTrOeeGRxAAHW@UzyFp3RyIrBbrd/)):

```
from random import choices
from timeit import repeat
from itertools import groupby

def Grismar1(a):
    if not a:
        return []
    sln = [a[0]]
    for x in a[1:]:
        if x % 2 != sln[-1] % 2:
            sln.append(x)
    return sln

def Grismar2(a):
    return [x for n, x in enumerate(a) if not n or x % 2 != a[n-1] % 2]

def Grismar3(a):
    return [] if not a else [a[0]] + [x for x, y in zip(a[1:], a) if x % 2 != y % 2]

def dont_talk1(a):
    return [x for x, y in zip(a, [.5] + a) if (x + y) % 2]

def dont_talk2(a):
    return [next(g) for _, g in groupby(a, 1 .__and__)]

solvers = Grismar1, Grismar2, Grismar3, dont_talk1, dont_talk2

# correctness (somewhat... only checks lengths)
for length in range(20):
    for _ in range(10):
        a = choices(range(100), k=length)
        expect = solvers[0](a[:])
        for solver in solvers:
            result = solver(a[:])
            assert len(result) == len(expect)

for _ in range(3):
    a = choices(range(100), k=10**6)
    for solver in solvers:
        copies = iter([a[:] for _ in range(5)])
        times = repeat(lambda: solver(next(copies)), number=1)
        print(*('%3d ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times), solver.__name__)
    print()
```